# Chrome ignores some imported certificates

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

On Windows 7 with Chrome 30. I have a few websites running on localhost over SSL. Visiting them always displays the standard "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" message from Chrome.

I exported the certificate from one of the sites in question and then, using the Certificate Import Wizard, imported it into Trusted Root Certification Authority. I double-checked in certmgr.msc, and the certificate is there as expected. After restarting Chrome, I still receive the same certificate error message as before.

I've tried different certificate file formats, but all exhibit this behavior. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Does the hostname in the URL agree with the name in the certificate? Check the certificate right in Chrome as it was transferred from the web server.

Comment: @pabouk I don't see a hostname field in the certificate.

Comment: There is no `hostname` field in certificates. The hostname (FQDN or IP address) should be specified in `subjectAltName` extension field or `subject` field and its `CN` identifier. ------ Browsers usually show reasons for rejecting a certificate. For example Firefox writes `adobe.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for www.adobe.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)`. In your case the message really shows that the CA which issued the certificate is not trusted. Chrome should use the "Trusted Root Certification Authority" Windows store.

Comment: Do other browsers show the same problem?

Comment: @pabouk The `subject` field in the cert is the name of the application running the webserver (`CN = MyApp`), but the hostname I use to connect is `localhost:9090`. Chrome gives 3 detail errors: `Server's certificate does not match the URL, Server's certificate is not trusted, Server's certificate is signed using a weak signature algorithm.` IE10 exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: You have to resolve all the three issues. Maybe the CA certificate is not trusted because of the weak signature algorithm? I have no experience with such problem -- CA is listed in trusted root CAs but an issued certificate from the CA is not trusted. Maybe you have some strict policy regarding CRLs?